# Issue saving images with PaperClip on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

Hoping you can help with me an issue I'm currently having.

I've set up [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to help me with image uploading and after following instructions and checking various guides, I believe it should be working, but I am running into an issue where it's simply not saving the image and displaying the following error. Can anyone point a learner in the right direction?

I've used imagemagick to convert via the command line without any issues.

**UPDATE**:
I've just looked through my files again and found that I've added this as it asked in the documentation. Do I need to amend the :command_path

**UPDATE 2**:
I have fixed the issue now and my resolution is the answer section belo.

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

.

```
There was an error processing the thumbnail for f87ef1d19d0a3693810436f1278205e020150803-666-1avrc9e
```

**The extracted source is as follows:**

```
def create
admin = Admin.new(admin_params)

if admin.save
  redirect_to '/administration'
```

**Parameters**

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"lZ9kDGwvbTUTElcOkKPrgpmiX9HlIfVpAXyRROk/jcRdoGJX9/unlBx6SuazNa9BXw0UIJhbmJiSUVin4DrsBg==",
 "admin"=>{"name"=>"fffsfdsa",
 "email"=>"dfsdfsfadsafsd@gmail.com",
 "user_name"=>"hjdfkhasdjhasjfdkh",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f9082386cf0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/t6/jrprg2rd57zch5mkt5cg_5cr0000gn/T/RackMultipart20150803-666-1crp2va.jpg>,
 @original_filename="image_name.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"admin[avatar]\"; filename=\"image_name.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">},
 "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

**Model (admin.rb)**

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
has_secure_password

has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => {
    :medium => "300x300>",
    :thumb => "50x50#>"},
    :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

**Admin Controller**

```
 class AdminController < ApplicationController
def new
end

def create
admin = Admin.new(admin_params)

if admin.save
  redirect_to '/administration'
  flash[:success] = "Admin account created successfully"
else
    flash[:error] = "Unable to create account"
  render 'administration/new_ai_admin'
end
end

private

def admin_params
params.require(:admin).permit(:name, :email, :user_name, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar)
end
end
```

Comment: Do you have ImageMagick installed? If yes, try this `sudo apt-get install imagemagick --fix-missing`

Comment: Hi, I have it installed and just tried to run the command and got the following message: Warning: imagemagick-6.9.1-10 already installed

Comment: What is the output of `which convert`? Perhaps Paperclip can't find ImageMagick at the default command path.

Comment: I'm getting the following: /usr/local/bin/convert .

I have updated my original question with something which might help find an answer.

Comment: Based on the output of `which convert` it looks like your command path is set correctly so I don't think that's the problem. Can you tell us what version of Rails and Paperclip you're using?

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. I'm running Rails version  4.2.0 and Paperclip 4.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Try use the Rails migration generator:

```
rails generate paperclip admin avatar
```

Comment: Hello. I have already added the migration to my admin table and these are showing when checking the table via terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to resolve the issue and it was simply a case of a mis-type in the model. Here is my working admin model

**admin.rb**
    class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_secure_password

```
has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => {
    :medium => "300x300>",
    :thumb => "50x50#"},
    :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```